# My data does not pass through to controller from Typescript view? I am using angular 5 .net core apllication 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, angular, typescript, post

Here is my code for Method in TypeScript
Ive been trying to pass an number[] array to the controller to send to a quickbooks api but all i really need right now is to get the values into the controller,
This is been done in Angular 5 .net core 2.0 latest version 
The data hits the Post Method with no error and i have breakpoints everywhere it never reaches the controller.

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
    import { Customer } from '../models/customer';
    import { Vendor } from '../models/vendor';
    import { Item } from '../models/item';
    import { Invoice } from '../models/invoice';
    import { CreditNote } from '../models/creditNote';
    import { PPO } from '../models/ppo';
    import { PO } from '../models/po';
    import { AppSettings } from '../models/appSettings';
    import { Http, Response, Headers, RequestOptions, RequestMethod, URLSearchParams } from '@angular/http';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    import { MsgResult } from '../models/msgResult';
    import { Router, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
    import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

        @Injectable()
        export class SyncDataService {
              errorMessage: string = "";
                    baseURL: string = 'http://localhost:56199/api';
                    constructor(private _http: Http, private route: ActivatedRoute, private router: Router) {}

                syncCustomers(ids: Array<number>) {



        var headers = new Headers();
                headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
                var localStorage1 = localStorage.getItem('access_token');
                if (localSt

orage1 != undefined) {
                var token = JSON.parse(localStorage1);

                //headers.append('Authorization', 'bearer ' + token);


                //return this._http.post(this.baseURL + '/customer', ids, options)
                //    .map((response: Response) => <string>response.json())
                //    .catch(err => {
                //        return this.handleError(err);
                //    });
                var stringids = JSON.stringify({ customerIDs: ids });

                this._http.post(this.baseURL + '/customer/PostCust',
                    stringids).subscribe(result => result.json()), err => {
                    return this.handleError(err);


                }

                }
            }
}
```

Here is my controller

```
 [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class CustomerController : Controller
    {
        private readonly SyncDbContext _dbContext;

        public CustomerController(SyncDbContext dbContext)
        {
            _dbContext = dbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public List<Customer> Get()
        {
            return new SyncDataManager().GetCustomers();
        }

        [HttpPost("[action]")]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public JsonResult PostCust([FromBody]int[] customerIDs)
        {
            // call quicbooks api and pass them the customers
            // once quickbooks verifys the customer and sends us back a reference
            // pass the quickbooks customer to SyncDataManager
            var sync = new SyncDataManager();

            var results = sync.UpdateCustomers(customerIDs);

            var failedResults = results.Where(m => m.Success == false).ToList();

            if(failedResults.Count == 0)
            {
                var json = new JsonResult("Updated Successfully");
                json.StatusCode = 200;
                return json;
            }
            else
            {
                var error = new StringBuilder();

                foreach (var errorMessage in failedResults)
                {
                    //string output = errorMessage.ErrorMessage.Substring(errorMessage.ErrorMessage.IndexOf('.') + 1);
                    string output = errorMessage.ErrorMessage;
                    error.AppendLine(output);
                }
                var json = new JsonResult(error.ToString());
                json.StatusCode = 400;
                return json;
            }
        }
```

There is no error messages and when i use break points on my controller, It does not hit the break points, been at it for 3 days no break through Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  this._http.post(this.baseURL + '/customer/PostCust',
            this.customerIDs).subscribe((data:Response) => { this.resu = (data.json() as string) },
           error => {
                alert(error.json());
            },
            () => {
               alert("Completed");
                } else {
                    this.RefreshCustomers();
                }

            });
```

this.resu is my results variable 
and no headers or casts for this.customerIDs this worked for me

Answer (score 1):

try in your Controller

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")] //<--include action
public class CustomerController : Controller
{
...
    [HttpGet,ActionName("Get")] //<--I don't know if it's necesary
    public List<Customer> Get() {..}

    [HttpPost, ActionName("PostCust")] //<--give there the "actionName
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public JsonResult PostCust([FromBody]int[] customerIDs){...}

}
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the response however after trying that the post still does not work, Im looking at debugging tools on chrome and still can't see any errors, this is so weird.

Comment: try use the "new" httpClient https://angular.io/guide/http and use simply _httpClient.post<int[]>(this.baseURL + '/customer/PostCust',ids)

Comment: Let me try again

Comment: I'm Kinda new to angular started 2 weeks ago if you can possibly show me an example that could post a number array towards the controller it will be appreciated  another thing is  im importing from from '@angular/http'; visual studio does not or my application does not pick up '@angular/common/http';

Comment: i tried this._http
            .post(this.baseURL + '/Customer/Post',
                body,
                {
                    headers: headers
                })
            .subscribe(data => {
                    alert('ok');
                },
                error => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error.json()));
                });
it hit ok alert but i dont know what this means

Comment: however it hit the alert still didnt hit the controller breakpoint

Comment: Response {_body: "", status: 415, ok: false, statusText: "Unsupported Media Type", headers: Headers, …}